# Fetch Param from Route in Nav Bar, React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a router set up in my App.js as follows:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './nav-bar';
import Landing from './landing-page';
import Dashboard from './dashboard';
import Analysis from './analysis';
import '../style.scss';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/:prodID/search" component={Dashboard} />
        <Redirect from="/dashboard/:prodID" to="/dashboard/:prodID/search" />
        <Route path="/dashboard/:prodID/analyze" component={Analysis} />
        <Route component={() => (
          <div id="error">
            <h1>404 ERROR</h1>
            <h2>Page not found</h2>
          </div>
        )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and my `NavBar` component is set up as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../style.scss';

class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar id="nav-bar" bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/">
          My Project
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav" className="justify-content-end">
          <Nav>
            <NavLink to="/dashboard/:prodID/search">Search</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/dashboard/:prodID/analyze">Analyze</NavLink>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

I have two things that I'm trying to figure out:

1. I want to be able to access the `prodID` route param within my NavBar component so that when a user clicks on the route, it will take the valid `prodID` and render the route correctly.
2. I want to only display the `NavLink`s in `NavBar` if the user is on a route that has the `prodID` param. If they're on the home route `/` for example, the links wouldn't show up. But if they're on the route `/dashboard/[valid prodID]/search`, the links would show up.

How do I go about implementing this? I've looked at other posts on SO dealing with route params and nav bars, but none of them have answered my question. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would have to move your navbar under each of the routes, so that it can be re-rendered and grab the correct params when the path changes.

In order to achieve it, you can create the Layout component which will wrap the component you pass and add a navbar to it:

```
// Layout.jsx
import React from "react";
import NavBar from './nav-bar';

export const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then in your App, you can wrap each component within the routes with the Layout component like so

```
// App.jsx    
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./nav-bar";
import Landing from "./landing-page";
import Dashboard from "./dashboard";
import Analysis from "./analysis";
import { Layout } from "./Layout";
import "../style.scss";

const App = props => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Layout>
            <Landing />
          </Layout>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/dashboard/:prodID/search">
          <Layout>
            <Dashboard />
          </Layout>
        </Route>
        <Redirect from="/dashboard/:prodID" to="/dashboard/:prodID/search" />
        <Route path="/dashboard/:prodID/analyze">
          <Layout>
            <Analysis />
          </Layout>
        </Route>
        <Route
          component={() => (
            <div id="error">
              <h1>404 ERROR</h1>
              <h2>Page not found</h2>
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This approach would help you achieve your second goal. Since the navbar is now nested under each route, you can easily fetch the params from the path and conditionally render the links, like so:

```
// NavBar.jsx
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import "../style.scss";

const NavBar = () => {
  const { prodID } = useParams();

  return (
    <Navbar id="nav-bar" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">My Project</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Collapse
        id="responsive-navbar-nav"
        className="justify-content-end"
      >
        <Nav>
          {prodID && (
            <NavLink to={`/dashboard/:${prodID}/search`}>Search</NavLink>
          )}
          {prodID && (
            <NavLink to={`/dashboard/:${prodID}/analyze`}>Analyze</NavLink>
          )}
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

I haven't tested it, but it should help you with your issues.

Comment: The `useParams` hook only works in `Route`. It won't work in the `NavBar` component which is outside any of the `Route` components

Comment: The ```Navbar``` is in the ```Layout``` component, which encapsulated every component inside each route. 
There was one instance of ```NavBar``` in the App component, which was a mistake. This is now removed.

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant idea !